# C++ - union with nontrivial class member type?

Tags: c++, inheritance, unions, diamond-problem

I'm working with a union which has a member that is a class that uses diamond inheritance, but the program encounters a segmentation fault upon assignment to this member.

My suspicion is that I need to add some copy constructors, but after multiple attempts, the correct way to do this still evades me.

I've included a minimal, reproducible example here.

```
struct Base
{
    Base() : a(0) {}
    Base(int x) : a(x) {}

    int a;
};

struct Derived1 : virtual public Base
{
    Derived1() {}
};

struct Derived2 : virtual public Base
{
    Derived2() {}
};

struct Final : public Derived1, public Derived2
{
    Final() {}
};

union Example
{
    Final value;
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    Example example{ Final() };
    example.i = -1;

    /* Segfault on the line below. 
     * If the above line

       example.i = -1;
     
     * is removed, the segfault is not encountered. */

    example.value = Final();
}
```

My thanks to anyone who knows how to do this.

Comment: That is how enums work.  `example.i = -1;` marks `int i;` as the active member, accessing other members is undefined behaviour. Do not try to do type punning with enums, it does not work in C++, the best you get is something called "common initial sequence" but that certainly does not apply to virtuals.

Comment: @Quimby you meant unions, not enums, right?

Comment: @Quimby Would it then be a sensible workaround to write a holder struct with `Final` and `int` members?

Comment: @Sugar Yes, of course, sorry, cannot edit the comment anymore anymore.

Comment: C++ unions are really annoying to use, prefer `std::variant` instead.

Comment: @ColdCrime I still do not know why you need an union? Please accept that you cannot access `Base::i` through `union::i`. Of course you can have `struct {Final value; int i;};`, not sure how is it relevant though.

Comment: @Quimby In a union where the members do not have non-trivial special member functions, _assigning_ to `i` would be ok even if `value` is the active member. It would effectively make `i` the active member.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The only case where this works is "common initial sequence", yes POD-like structure having an `int` member qualifies, but not for the same reasons as in C. Type punning through unions is explciitly allowed only in C, not in C++.

Comment: @Quimby "_Type punning through unions is explciitly allowed only in C, not in C++_" - Yes, but I don't see OP trying to do type punning here. OP is not writing to one member and then trying to read from another member.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Wow, apparently I cannot read nor write today, so sorry. In this case disregard everything I said in this comment section :D

Comment: @Quimby :-) Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `Base` class is [virtual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class#Virtual_base_classes), most likely there are some internal control structures, which become destroyed, when you assign

```
example.i = -1;
```

When you recreate `value`, e.g.

```
new(&example.value) Final();
example.value = Final();
```

before the assignment, the segmentation fault goes away. Although, I wouldn't recommend this hack.

---

As already mentioned in the comments, a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) would be more appropriate, if you have C++17 available. The example would then become

```
std::variant<Final, int> example{ Final() };
example = -1;
example = Final();
```

Comment: This is not a "hack", it is the legal way of using unions. The later assignment is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Begin with c++11, unions with members that define their own constructors
and/or copy-control members are allowed but When a union has members of built-in type, we can use ordinary assignment to
change the value that the union holds, but Not for unions that have members of
nontrivial class types. When we switch the union’s value to and from a member of
class type, we must construct or destroy that member. for example see bellow code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new> // for placement new

class Type   // non built in type with constructors
{
private:
    int val;

public:
    Type() : val{0} {    }

    explicit Type(int v) : val{v}  {  }

    Type(const Type &obj) : val{obj.val} {  }

    int getval()  {   return val;  }
};

class unionexample   // I enclose union with class for readability
{
private:
    enum { INT,TYPE } OBJ;

    union
    {
        Type Tval;  // non build in type
        int ival;   // build in type
    };

public:
    unionexample() : ival{0}, OBJ{INT} // default with int
    { }

    unionexample(const unionexample &obj) : OBJ{obj.OBJ}
    {
        switch (obj.OBJ)
        {
        case INT:
            this->ival = obj.ival;
            break;
        case TYPE:
            new (&this->Tval) Type(obj.Tval);
            break;
        }
    }

    unionexample &operator=(int v)
    {
        if (OBJ == TYPE)
        {
            Tval.~Type(); // if it is TYPE destruct it
        }

        ival = v; // assign

        OBJ = INT;

        return *this;
    }

    unionexample &operator=(Type v)
    {
        if (OBJ == TYPE)
        {
            Tval = v;  // if it is alderdy Type just assign
        }

        new (&Tval) Type(v); // else construct

        OBJ = TYPE;

        return *this;
    }

    void print()
    {
        switch (OBJ)
        {
        case INT:
            std::cout << "ival = " << ival << std::endl;
            break;

        case TYPE:
            std::cout << "Tval = " << Tval.getval() << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    ~unionexample()
    {
        if (OBJ == TYPE)  // if it is TYPE we must destruct it
            Tval.~Type();
    }
};

int main()
{
    unionexample ue;
    ue.print();
    ue = Type(1);
    ue.print();
}
```

output:

```
ival = 0
Tval = 1
```

[Run Here](https://onlinegdb.com/B1dqGW9rP)

In Your case

```
int main()
{
    Example example{ value : Final() };     // construct with Final

    example.value.~Final();                 // destruct Final

    example.i = -1;                         // assign int built in type
    
    new(&example.value)  Final();           // construct
    
    example.value.~Final();                 // destruct finally
}
```

If you asked this question other than learning purpose you can use `std::variant` as in other answer.

Thanks.